# Have `xargs` run the arguments it's received every <maximum amount of time> instead of every `-n` arguments?

Tags: shell-script, osx, xargs, inotify

I am using `fswatch` and `xargs` to watch for file system changes, and run commands depending on which files are changing.  `fswatch` prints the changed files to stdout, and `xargs <my command>` consumes them from stdin.

If I use `xargs -n1`, my command will run after every change.  If I use `xargs -n100`, my command won't run until there have been 100 changes.  I'd like to batch all of the changes (arguments) that occur within 1 second.

If xargs receives 50 lines on stdin at once, I'd like xargs to pass all 50 of them to my command in a single invocation, rather than 50 separate invocations as with `xargs -n1`.  But if xargs only receives 1 line per minute, I don't want to wait 50 minutes before my command is invoked; I want it to be relatively interactive (i.e. ~1 second maximum, provided that xargs has received a nonzero number of arguments on stdin).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note, `fswatch` has a [--batch-marker](http://emcrisostomo.github.io/fswatch/doc/1.12.0/fswatch.html/Tutorial-Introduction-to-fswatch.html) option that puts a special `NoOp` line in the output after a "burst".

Comment: @meuh I think this is the best answer for me.

Answer (score 4):

If you can use Bash, you could use the `-t` (timeout) option for `read`, and/or the `SECONDS` variable.

This is a bit ugly but works to group input that comes roughly within a second:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do 
        values=()
        start=$SECONDS
        while [ "$SECONDS" -lt $((start + 1)) ]; do
                if IFS= read -r -t 1 line; then
                        values+=("$line")
                fi
        done
        if [ "${#values[@]}" != 0 ]; then
                echo got "${values[@]}"
                # do something useful with "${values[@]}" here 
        fi
done
```

The timeout on `read` keeps it from blocking forever, and the test against `SECONDS` makes sure that the inner loop is broken even in the pathological case where `read` gets input once per second, for ever.

Answer (score 1):

Use Lsyncd instead of reinventing the wheel;

```
lsyncd -rsyncssh /home remotehost.org backup-home/
```

https://github.com/axkibe/lsyncd/blob/master/README.md

> Lsyncd watches a local directory trees event monitor interface (inotify or fsevents). It aggregates and combines events for a few seconds and then spawns one (or more) process(es) to synchronize the changes.

Comment: This answer would be a lot more useful if you added an example of how to use it (and maybe a link to the software itself).

Comment: I’m not sure how this relates to my question, as I wasn’t asking how to sync files.  Could you clarify?